# jQuery tool tip not appearing on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-widgets

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("img").tooltip();  
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>About Us</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</script> 

</head>

<body>

        <img src="g.png" title="WIll SMITH WAS HERE">

</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js" integrity="sha512-HkAISJ55u/2jGG42Bet54ZmPM+7+XKCY84JsDoKGYK98EeVGg5Ka/NcvnE4lYCzbX3+aGN46rpShBtDLg1wo9w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-57oZ/vW8ANMjR/KQ6Be9v/+/h6bq9/l3f0Oc7vn6qMqyhvPd1cvKBRWWpzu0QoneImqr2SkmO4MSqU+RpHom3Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</html>
```

Explain

I tried the way jquery website provied

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  } );
  </script>
```

still didn't work for me. I want the title to appear when hovering over the image. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you had a typo in your original code which was missing the closing quote on the image's `alt` attribute. I've corrected your code and it seems to work in this example.

Comment: @kmoser could you provide code as it still not working properly for me

Comment: @kmoser no ned to provide it i see that you. had edited it, thank you!!